# AX 2012 R3 error message: Out of memory

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

While I try to start my AX client, it raises up to 1.9 GB on memory consumption. A little after that an info box pops up with the message: "Out of Memory". 
My environment currently runs on 6 Gbs of RAM. 
Another user tried to login using his credentials to make sure it wasn't user profile related. He got the same error. 
I have tried restarting my environment, uninstalling and reinstalling my client, but none of these worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is SQL on the same server as the AOS? Try with 8GB of RAM as this is minimal [system requirement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361989.aspx) (p. 7).

Comment: No, SQL and the AOS are in different servers. On my server itself I have 32GB of RAM. The 6GB mentioned earlier are from my client machine.

Comment: Can you check and add the event log?

Comment: Is your client running in *en-us*?

Comment: Yes, the client is running in en-us. Here is the log event that it raises.
`The description for Event ID 110 from source Microsoft Dynamics AX cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Microsoft Dynamics AX Business Connector Session 26.


Out of memory.`

Comment: Can it be that the client performs a CIL compilation at startup? Using the client configuration commands `-startupcmd=CompileIL`

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of troubleshooting it end up being disk corruption. Had to completely re-image entire system. Thanks for all the suggestions.